# How can I know if the customer that made the order is guest or registered customer?

Tags: orders, customer

The problem is that I am sending the Magento order to an external `ERP` and they need the customer id from Magento.

the problem comes when the customer is guest because in theory this customer doesn't have an id but I am not sure. Is there a way to check if the customer is a guest?

I am using the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` object in order to get the information I need from the customer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to know if the customer is guest or not. trigger `getCustomerIsGuest()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` I believe that can get customer instance of order.

Answer (score 8):

as you said `I am using the Mage_Sales_Model_Order object in order to get the information` then:

```
if($order->getCustomerIsGuest()){
    // customer is guest
}else{
    $customerid = $order->getCustomer()->getId();
    //send the customer id to your external ERP
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I was wondering if this really existed. I am going to check this and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in SQL, for one customer.

```
select
   entity_id,
   increment_id,
   customer_is_guest
from
   sales_flat_order
where
   increment_id = 101125260
;
```

Outputs:

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
| entity_id | increment_id | customer_is_guest |
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|   2371223 | 101125260    |                 1 |
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

To generate a histogram and understand the percentage of your users which are logged in when checking out.

```
select
   if(customer_id, 1, 0) as loggedin,
   count(*)
from
   sales_flat_order
where
   created_at > '2018-11-01'
group by
   1
order by
   1 desc
;
```

Outputs:

```
+----------+----------+
| loggedin | count(*) |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |     1194 |
|        0 |     1693 |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be checked by observer:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
$guestCustomer = $order->getCustomerIsGuest();
groupId  = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
```

we can get all type of customer data using observer.